# Dead ID pin on DELL AC adapter, how can i run the CPU on 100% anyways?

Tags: grub2, dell, power-management

I have a Dell D430 with Lubuntu 14.04 (if i'm not wrong about the version) installed. My power adapter failed with its ID pin, but it's powering the unit. I don't care of charging the battery, it will be removed.

The laptop now runs on the lowest possible frequency due to Dell's restrictions. I learned earlier that the CPU frequency can be forced to be high, but I don't know how. It's GRUB2 what can do this thing on my system, but I don't know what to write and where in the configuration files. And I want this setting to be permanent.

I wanna give the laptop to my son, he plays flash games in browser anyways. I read that the 10_LINUX file should be modified in `/etc/grub.d` folder.

Can anybody help me out with this? 
I'm new to this, forgive if I asked stupid things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get around the missing ID pin on Dell Laptop chargers by adding (as root) `processor.ignore_ppc=1` to your `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` line in your `/etc/default/grub` file.

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="processor.ignore_ppc=1"
```

afterwards run:

```
sudo update-grub
```

then reboot.

Note: this will allow your normal CPU frequency scaling to work properly, just as if the ID were working properly, but does not always force the maximum CPU frequency.

Note: Use this at your own risk. It disables the BOIS limiting the CPU frequency, which is a most primitive level of protection.